# Java Slick2D: Camera is scrolling, character moves too fast

Tags: java, slick2d

I've been playing around with Slick2D for Java and I managed to get it to display maps and have my character sprite move around.

I've tried to implement a camera that follows the player so that the map scrolls. While the map is scrolling, that characters move speed is faster than it should be (possibly due to the camera srolling it as well as it moving with the keys)

I'm stumped on how to solve it though

The camera code is something i found on the slick forums, and modified slightly to draw each layer seperatly, modifying both drawmap methods to add the layer in. I would ask on the forums but they seem dead.

This is the camera code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package engine;

/**
 *
 * @author Ceri
 */
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Shape;
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap;

public class Camera {

    /**
     * the map used for our scene
     */
    protected TiledMap map;

    /**
     * the number of tiles in x-direction (width)
     */
    protected int numTilesX;

    /**
     * the number of tiles in y-direction (height)
     */
    protected int numTilesY;

    /**
     * the height of the map in pixel
     */
    protected int mapHeight;

    /**
     * the width of the map in pixel
     */
    protected int mapWidth;

    /**
     * the width of one tile of the map in pixel
     */
    protected int tileWidth;

    /**
     * the height of one tile of the map in pixel
     */
    protected int tileHeight;

    /**
     * the GameContainer, used for getting the size of the GameCanvas
     */
    protected GameContainer gc;

    /**
     * the x-position of our "camera" in pixel
     */
    protected float cameraX;

    /**
     * the y-position of our "camera" in pixel
     */
    protected float cameraY;

    protected Point2D.Float currentCenterPoint = new Point2D.Float(0, 0);

    /**
     * Create a new camera
     *
     * @param gc the GameContainer, used for getting the size of the GameCanvas
     * @param map the TiledMap used for the current scene
     */
    public Camera(GameContainer gc, TiledMap map) {
        this.map = map;

        this.numTilesX = map.getWidth();
        this.numTilesY = map.getHeight();

        this.tileWidth = map.getTileWidth();
        this.tileHeight = map.getTileHeight();

        this.mapWidth = this.numTilesX * this.tileWidth;
        this.mapHeight = this.numTilesY * this.tileHeight;

        this.gc = gc;
    }

    /**
     * "locks" the camera on the given coordinates. The camera tries to keep the
     * location in it's center.
     *
     * @param x the real x-coordinate (in pixel) which should be centered on the
     * screen
     * @param y the real y-coordinate (in pixel) which should be centered on the
     * screen
     * @return
     */
    public Point2D.Float centerOn(float x, float y) {
        //try to set the given position as center of the camera by default
        cameraX = x - gc.getWidth() / 2;
        cameraY = y - gc.getHeight() / 2;

        //if the camera is at the right or left edge lock it to prevent a black bar
        if (cameraX < 0) {
            cameraX = 0;
        }
        if (cameraX + gc.getWidth() > mapWidth) {
            cameraX = mapWidth - gc.getWidth();
        }

        //if the camera is at the top or bottom edge lock it to prevent a black bar
        if (cameraY < 0) {
            cameraY = 0;
        }
        if (cameraY + gc.getHeight() > mapHeight) {
            cameraY = mapHeight - gc.getHeight();
        }

        currentCenterPoint.setLocation(cameraX, cameraY);
        return currentCenterPoint;
    }

    /**
     * "locks" the camera on the center of the given Rectangle. The camera tries
     * to keep the location in it's center.
     *
     * @param x the x-coordinate (in pixel) of the top-left corner of the
     * rectangle
     * @param y the y-coordinate (in pixel) of the top-left corner of the
     * rectangle
     * @param height the height (in pixel) of the rectangle
     * @param width the width (in pixel) of the rectangle
     */
    public void centerOn(float x, float y, float height, float width) {
        this.centerOn(x + width / 2, y + height / 2);
    }

    /**
     * "locks the camera on the center of the given Shape. The camera tries to
     * keep the location in it's center.
     *
     * @param shape the Shape which should be centered on the screen
     */
    public void centerOn(Shape shape) {
        this.centerOn(shape.getCenterX(), shape.getCenterY());
    }

    /**
     * draws the part of the map which is currently focussed by the camera on
     * the screen
     */
    public void drawMap(int layer) {
        this.drawMap(0, 0, layer);
    }

    /**
     * draws the part of the map which is currently focussed by the camera on
     * the screen.<br>
     * You need to draw something over the offset, to prevent the edge of the
     * map to be displayed below it<br>
     * Has to be called before Camera.translateGraphics() !
     *
     * @param offsetX the x-coordinate (in pixel) where the camera should start
     * drawing the map at
     * @param offsetY the y-coordinate (in pixel) where the camera should start
     * drawing the map at
     */
    public void drawMap(int offsetX, int offsetY, int layer) {
        //calculate the offset to the next tile (needed by TiledMap.render())
        int tileOffsetX = (int) -(cameraX % tileWidth);
        int tileOffsetY = (int) -(cameraY % tileHeight);

        //calculate the index of the leftmost tile that is being displayed
        int tileIndexX = (int) (cameraX / tileWidth);
        int tileIndexY = (int) (cameraY / tileHeight);

        //finally draw the section of the map on the screen
        map.render(
                tileOffsetX + offsetX,
                tileOffsetY + offsetY,
                tileIndexX,
                tileIndexY,
                (gc.getWidth() - tileOffsetX) / tileWidth + 1,
                (gc.getHeight() - tileOffsetY) / tileHeight + 1, layer, false);
    }

    /**
     * Translates the Graphics-context to the coordinates of the map - now
     * everything can be drawn with it's NATURAL coordinates.
     */
    public void translateGraphics() {
        gc.getGraphics().translate(-cameraX, -cameraY);
    }

    /**
     * Reverses the Graphics-translation of Camera.translatesGraphics(). Call
     * this before drawing HUD-elements or the like
     */
    public void untranslateGraphics() {
        gc.getGraphics().translate(cameraX, cameraY);
    }

}
```

and this is how its being called
In the engine class

```
    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

            camera = new Camera(gc, world.map);
            camera.centerOn(player.getX(), player.getY());
            camera.drawMap(0);
            camera.drawMap(1);
            player.draw();
            camera.drawMap(2);
        }
```

This is how the player class is

```
public Player(MapClass m) throws SlickException {
        map = m;

        Image[] movementUp = {new Image("Images/Player/u1.png"), new Image("Images/Player/u2.png"), new Image("Images/Player/u3.png"), new Image("Images/Player/u4.png")};
        Image[] movementDown = {new Image("Images/Player/d1.png"), new Image("Images/Player/d2.png"), new Image("Images/Player/d3.png"), new Image("Images/Player/d4.png")};
        Image[] movementLeft = {new Image("Images/Player/l1.png"), new Image("Images/Player/l2.png"), new Image("Images/Player/l3.png"), new Image("Images/Player/l4.png")};
        Image[] movementRight = {new Image("Images/Player/r1.png"), new Image("Images/Player/r2.png"), new Image("Images/Player/r3.png"), new Image("Images/Player/r4.png")};
        int[] duration = {100, 100, 100, 100};

        up = new Animation(movementUp, duration, false);
        down = new Animation(movementDown, duration, false);
        left = new Animation(movementLeft, duration, false);
        right = new Animation(movementRight, duration, false);

        // Original orientation of the sprite. It will look right.
        sprite = right;
    }

public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException {
        Input input = container.getInput();
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
            sprite = up;
            sprite.update(delta);
            // The lower the delta the slowest the sprite will animate.
            if (!map.isBlocked(x, y - delta * 0.1f))
                y -= delta * 0.1f;
        } else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
            sprite = down;
            sprite.update(delta);
            if (!map.isBlocked(x, y + 16 + delta * 0.1f))
                y += delta * 0.1f;
        } else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
            sprite = left;
            sprite.update(delta);
            if (!map.isBlocked(x - delta * 0.1f, y))
                x -= delta * 0.1f;
        } else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
            sprite = right;
            sprite.update(delta);
            if (!map.isBlocked(x + 16 + delta * 0.1f, y))
                x += delta * 0.1f;
        }
    }

    public void draw() {
        sprite.draw(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: How are you manipulating the character's position?

Comment: Its done in the Player class. It has a method update which is called from the main update. I've added the code to the first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Moved the map draw out of the camera class into the map class. used the camera x/y created in the camera class in the map and player class